# return a object with parameter

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, return

I've an object called 'sheet1'

```
var nr = 1;
function Sheet(title){
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.dataset.sheetNr = nr;
    this.div.dataset.sheetTitle = title;
    document.getElementById("sheets").appendChild(this.div);
    nr++;
}

Sheet.prototype = {
    constructor: Sheet,
    get : function(data){
        return this.div.dataset.data;
    }
}

var sheet1 = new Sheet("Title1");
```

now when I call the function

```
sheet1.get("sheetNr");
```

it returns 'undefined' !...how can I solve this problem?

```
// console.log(data); outputs sheetNr
```

but when I change my function like

```
Sheet.prototype = {
    constructor: Sheet,
    get : function(){
        return this.div.dataset.sheetNr;
    }
}
```

and then call
    sheet1.get();
it returns the number of the sheet...1 in this case...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOXZjq?editors=101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a data attribute defined on the div you are creating sot it doesn't exist as called. When you call `this.div.dataset.sheetNr` you are actually hitting a defined attribute. To use the variable `data` as an index you need to call:
`this.div.dataset[data]` instead.